# Simplify the invocation of a common method

Tags: methods, operator-keyword, raku

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    method some-method(Str $name) { ... }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
my $foo = Foo.new;

$foo.some-method("peter");
```

Since the "some-method" will be called quite frequently,  I'd like to do something to allow users to use it like below:

```
$foo.peter;
```

I know FALLBACK will do the job, but it has been used for another method.
I tried to define an infix operator:

```
sub infix:<%>(Foo $foo, $name) {
    $foo.some-method($name);
}
```

The code below works, but the double quote is annoying.

```
$foo % "peter";
```

So is there any way to avoid the quote mark? Or any way to simplify the invocation?

Comment: I've used FALLBACK for this, but since your arg is a simple Str, you could make it an Associative and just use method AT-KEY and call it with `$foo<peter>`.

Comment: [`FALLBACK` supports multi methods and subsignatures](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_%28method%29). As long as you can distinguish between different invocations (for instance, by checking on method name, or its parameters) you should be able to use it for as many methods as you want.

Comment: Might this work? Gotta run and haven't tested but maybe use the MOP to generate and export appropriately constrained postfixes? Something like (sans MOPing) `class c { module { sub postfix:<.foo> (c $_) is export { .say } } }; import c; c.foo; # (c)`.

Comment: @raiph Do I need to define the operator before using it?

Comment: @lovetomato yes, you do.  Always.  Otherwise Perl 6 won't know how to parse it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Curt Tilmes already pointed out, you could make your `Foo` object act as an `Associative` (or `Hash`):

```
class Foo {
    method some-method(Str $name) { ... }
    method AT-KEY(Str $name) { self.some-method($name) }
}
my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo<peter>;   # same as $foo.some-method("peter")
```

Of course, the `AT-KEY` method can be a multi, so you could play all sorts of tricks with that as well.

```
class Foo {
    method some-method(Str $name) { "$name is ok" }
    multi method AT-KEY("peter")   { "peter is special" }
    multi method AT-KEY(Str $name) { self.some-method($name) }
}
my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo<peter>;   # "peter is special"
say $foo<joe>;     # "joe is ok"
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a way that you can use `FALLBACK` for more than one operation, provided they are different in some way.

- By checking some property of the object:

  ```perl6
  class Foo {
    # this could be set as part of `new`/`BUILD`
    has %!special = ( "peter" => 42 );

    multi method FALLBACK ( $name where (%!special{$name}:exists) ) {
      %!special{$name}
    }

    multi method FALLBACK ( $other ) {
      $other.tc
    }
  }

  with Foo.new {
    say .paul; # Paul
    say .peter; # 42
  }
  ```

  This has the potential problem of action-at-a-distance.
- With different number or types of arguments:

  ```perl6
  class Bar {
    multi method FALLBACK ( Str:D $name ) {
      $name.tc
    }
    multi method FALLBACK ( Str:D $name, Real:D $number ) {
      $name.tc, 1 / $number
    }
    multi method FALLBACK ( Str:D $name, Str:D $other ) {
      $name.tc, $other.uc
    }
  }

  with Bar.new {
    say .paul;          # Paul
    say .peter(42);     # Peter, 0.02381
    say .peter('Paul'); # Peter, PAUL
  }
  ```

---

You can use `.[…]` for an Int argument.

```perl6
class Baz {
  method AT-POS ( $arg ) { say "Baz[$arg]" }
}
Baz.new[42,32]; # Baz[42]
                # Baz[32]
```

The built-in `postcircumfix:« [ ] »` coerces the arguments to Int, but you could add a new one into the mix.
(There are a bunch of caveats with doing this.)

```perl6
multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Baz:D $b, $a ) is export {
  # $b.AT-POS( $a )

  $b.some-method( $a )
}
```

---

You can use `.<…>` for space separated Strs or `.{…}` for arbitrary values.

```perl6
class Other {
  multi method AT-KEY ( Str:D $name ){
    $name.tc
  }
  multi method AT-KEY ( Real:D $number ){
    1 / $number
  }
}

with Other.new {
  say $_<peter>;     # Peter
  say $_.<paul>;     # Paul
  say .<peter paul>; # Peter Paul
  # note that AT-Key got called twice

  say $_{42,'peter'}; # 0.02381, Peter
  # note that AT-Key got called twice
}
```

---

You can make it so that your object is callable.

```perl6
class Fubar {
  multi method CALL-ME ( Str:D $name ){
    $name.tc
  }
  multi method CALL-ME ( Real:D $number ){
    1 / $number
  }
  multi method CALL-ME ( +@args ){
    @args.map: {self.CALL-ME($_)}
  }
}

with Fubar.new {
  say $_('peter');   # Peter
  say $_(42);        # 0.02381

  # this calls the +@args one
  say $_('paul',32); # Paul, 0.03125
}
```

---

You should really think about your API before doing any of these.